# Xcode 6.3 - Crash on Archive, NSOperationQueue

Tags: crash, xcode6, nsoperationqueue

Xcode Version 6.3.2 
The coding project: Objective-C

I can not send the application to Apple, I get this error when upload.

Can you help to correct the error?

```
Crashed Thread:        15  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fb2c8a0bf50 :: NSOperation 0x7fb2c8bf5480 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D2105
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7718/IDEFoundation/Issues/IDEIssueManager.m:457
Details:  This method must only be called on the main thread
Object:   <IDEIssueManager>
Method:   +_issueProviderInfo
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb2c75fbc90>{number = 21, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
```

Answer (score 1):

Close "workspace/project view", leave only "Organiser View" opened and submit your app.

Comment: I'm in awe that this just fixed my problem. That has never happened before, but this little nugget of advice actually fixed. Xcode was consistently crashing at the upload portion of the Submit App.